# ansible playbook - how to avoid including var file multiple times

Tags: ansible

**Problem**

I have a playbook that i'd like to run with specific tags.  Currently, it fails with an undefined variable error.  The variable is defined in a file that i include in main.yml, but it's not visible to another yml file that i include via the "import_tasks" function.

The work around I have is to include the same var file everywhere I reference variables.  But I'd like to know if there's a simpler way to do this / if my approach is wrong.

**YML Code**

I have the following folder structure for my playbook:

```
tasks/main.yml
     /initialize-postgresql.yml
     /setup-db.yml
vars/debos.yml
```

The debos.yml var file looks like this:

```
__postgresql_version: "12"
__postgresql_daemon: "postgresql"
__postgresql_data_dir: "/var/lib/postgresql/{{ __postgresql_version }}/data"
__postgresql_bin_path: "/usr/lib/postgresql/"
__postgresql_config_path: "/etc/postgresql/"
__postgresql_user: "postgres"
__postgresql_group: "postgres"
__postgresql_packages:
  - postgresql
  - postgresql-contrib
```

In main.yml, I have the following code (only relevant parts included):

```
  - delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    block:

    # Variable configuration.
    - include_vars: debos.yml    


    #Using import_ vs. include_ for the sake of tags.
    - import_tasks: initialize-postgresql.yml
      tags: init-db
```

initialize-postgresql.yml looks like this in part:

```
---
# Variable configuration.
- include_vars: alpine.yml   

- name: define local vars
  set_fact: 
    postgresql_data_dir: "{{ __postgresql_data_dir }}"
    postgresql_group: "{{ __postgresql_group }}"
    postgresql_user: "{{ __postgresql_user }}"  
    postgresql_config_path: "{{ __postgresql_config_path }}"
    postgresql_daemon: "{{ __postgresql_daemon }}"
```

In order to be able to run may play book with a tag like this:

```
 ansible-playbook -i inventory/dbs installpsqldb.yml --tags "init-db"
```

I have to include the debos.yml file again in initialize-postgresql.yml file.  If not I get errors about undefined variables.

Ultimately in tasks, I'm going to have more yml files and they will all use the same variables.  So I'd like to make sure that I've set things up properly where properly is:

- having the ability to split out tasks into separate yml files.
- call yml files by tagname.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Review the documentation about [`tags`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html).

There is a special one called [`always`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags) that always runs the task as its name suggests.

Just put that tag on your `include_vars` task and that should do the trick.